# How to prevent deletion of Django model from Django Admin, unless part of a cascade

Tags: python, django

I have a project using Django 2.2.4.

I have a Django model called Company.

I use a post_save signal to make sure that as soon as a new Company is created, a new model instance called "Billing" is created, which is associated with that Company. This contains the company's billing information. This works great.

Since my Billing object is associated with a Company, and I use `on_delete=models.CASCADE`, as soon as the Company is deleted, the Billing object associated with that company is automatically deleted as well. This works great too.

Since the Billing object for each company is now automatically created and deleted along with the Company, there's no need for admins using the Django Admin web interface to ever have to manually create, or delete Billing objects. I want to hide this functionality from them.

Normally, the common way to prevent Django Admin from allowing someone to add or delete an object is by adding this to that model's ModelAdmin in admin.py:

```
class BillingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    # Prevent deletion from admin portal
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    # Prevent adding from admin portal
    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

This works, and does indeed hide the ability for Admins to create or delete instances of the Billing object manually. It does however have one negative side-effect: Django Admin users can no longer delete a company. When deleting a company, Django does a lookup for all associated objects that need to also be deleted, notices that the user isn't allowed to delete the associated Billing object, and prevents the user from deleting the Company.

While I don't want Django Admin users to be able to manually create or delete instances of the Billing model, I still want them to be able to delete an entire Company, which will result in the deletion of the instance of the Billing model associated with that Company.

In my case, preventing users from deleting an instance of the Billing model isn't so much a security feature, as it is intended to prevent confusion, by not letting the database end up in a state where a Company exists, but no billing object exists for it. Django would obviously not have a problem with this, but it would confuse users.

Is there a workaround for this?

Update:

With the `has_delete_permission` set, if you try to delete a company through Django Admin, you get this:

[image]

No exceptions are thrown. At least none that aren't caught, and appear in the Django logs.

My Models look like this:

```
class Company(Group):
    ...

class Billing(models.Model):
    company = AutoOneToOneField('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False, related_name="billing")
    monthly_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=False, null=False)

# Create billing object for a company when it is first created
@receiver(post_save, sender=Company)
def create_billing_for_company(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Billing.objects.create(company=instance)
```

The AutoOneToOneField is part of django-annoying. It makes sure that if you run MyCompany.billing, and an associated billing object doesn't exist yet, one will be created automatically, rather than an exception being raised. May not be required here, since I automatically create the object when the company is created, but it can't hurt, and ensures my code never needs to worry about the associated object not existing.

Also note that I have NOT overridden my Billing model's `delete` function.

Comment: Opinion: You shouldn't delete things anyway. I mean it in the nicest way possible, but end users are bad at not messing things up. Why would you let them drop a value and then CASCADE it??? Add a status/active field on the model and 'soft delete' it by setting it to 0. Deletions are reserved for DBA's or people other than end users.

Comment: @dfundako We're not talking about users. We're talking about Administrators. Users of the Django Admin web interface. And since the Django Admin web interface is essentially an interface into the DB, these users are, more or less, DBAs. And the fact that `people are bad at not messing things up` is exactly why I'm attempting to prevent them from deleting a Billing object, which should exist while a company exists, and not exist when the company is deleted.

Comment: IMHO: I think @dfundako is talking about any kind of users, Administrators are a kind of users and I agree to avoid deletions is a best practice, a bad action from an administrator could cause a BIG issue in your system. Change deletions by boolean values (active / inactive) is the best approach, if your problem is storage limitation, you can build an script to delete every month inactive records for example.

Comment: I don't have unlimited time to work on this project. I have 10 other projects waiting for me. I'm not spending a week developing a complex system to prevent Administrators from deleting a company, when there are already warnings in Django Admin that tells Admins exactly what will be deleted, and force them to confirm before deleting anything. Chances are, I'll be the one using Django Admin when this goes into production 6 - 12 months from now. I know not to delete a Company unless I'm sure, but I may not remember the details of the Billing model, or if I'm supposed to add/delete it.

Comment: what you want is just hide the 'delete' option entirely from the template, you can override the `Billing` model's "[add form template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#custom-template-options)"  by duplicating the default template and removing the delete button from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a little digging, it [does appear](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1083-L1087) that the `ModelAdmin` will simply call `delete()` on the object, meaning that it shouldn't look at your billing permissions for admin specifically. [Looking at the model delete](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L920-L929) also confirms that it does not care what the admin permissions are.

I got curious, and wondered if maybe the `has_delete_permission` function looks at related objects. [That also didn't appear to be the case](https://github.com/django/django/blob/42b9a23267f14be39b9b00958e18d5746783208e/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L491-L504). At this point, I'm curious if you have overridden your `Billing` model's `delete` function? That would prevent deletion, and if you have `CASCADE` set as your `on_delete` for the relation, it would not allow you to finish deleting the `Company` at that point because it was unable to cascade delete.

If you have a stack trace or explicit error message, please share it.

---

With that said, I don't know if I agree with the approach to this. I think it would make more sense to enforce this at the model level of `Billing`. When attempting a `delete`, you could check if there are no other `Billing` objects for the `Company`, and if so, raise a validation error notifying the user that a `Company` must have at least one `Billing`. I don't know your models since they aren't posted, so if it's a one-to-one relation, please ignore this. Here's a rough idea of how I would expect it to look otherwise:

```py
def delete(self):
    other_billing = Billing.objects.filter(company_id=self.company.id).exclude(id=self.id).first()
    if not other_billing:
        raise ValidationError({"message": "A company must have at least one Billing."})
    super().delete()
```

**Edit**: Here's a method using [`ModelAdmin.delete_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.delete_model) which won't raise an exception.

```py
def delete_model(self, request, billing):
    other_billing = Billing.objects.filter(company_id=billing.company.id).exclude(id=billing.id).first()
    if not other_billing:
        # from django.contrib import messages
        messages.error(request, "A company must have at least one Billing.")
    else:
        super().delete_model(request, billing)
```

---

**EDIT:** I did find that you have access to the `request`, which seems to be the only reliable way via `has_delete_permissions()` to check whether you're on the admin change page for your model or not. For the record **I think this way is hacky and I don't recommend it**. However, it would allow for cascading deletes while not allowing delete via the change page (it will hide the button):

```py
def has_delete_permissions(self, request, obj=None):
    # If we have an object, it's been fetched for deletion or to check permission against it.
    if isinstance(obj, Billing):
        if request.path == reverse("admin:<APP_NAME>_billing_change", args=[obj.id]):
            return False

    return True
```

Comment: A `ValidationError` raised in the `delete()` method is in general just going to "crash" whatever you're doing (view would return a 500 error) because validation errors aren't caught at that level. They are only caught when running `clean()` on a model.

Comment: @dirkgroten Ah, interesting. I haven't had to really try to do this, so that's good to know. Would it make sense then use `clean()` here then? I know generally it's used as part of a `save()`.

Comment: A model's `clean()` method isn't called when deleting it through `ModelAdmin` so that wouldn't help.

Comment: You could manually call as part of `delete()`. It's not automatically called by `save()` either.

Comment: No it's not called from `save()` but it's always called when submitting a form and cleaning it. That's also where the validations are caught (`form.is_valid()`). The thing is that for the delete action, there isn't form validation.

Comment: But you could use the [`ModelAdmin.delete_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.delete_model) method for this. Only call the `super()` method if there is another billing, otherwise, just not do anything, adding a message with an error to the `request` that is passed into `delete_model`.

Comment: I appreciate the edit and insight @dirkgroten. I don't often add custom admin form logic (or use Django Model Forms anymore for that matter). Thank you!

Comment: I might be missing something, but would this not break when deleting a company? If you delete a company, it will try to delete the Billing object, which will quickly figure out that there are no other billing objects associated with that company, and refuse to be deleted?

Comment: I think you're right for my suggestion @John. @dirkgroten Made an edit suggesting a `delete_model()` check on the `ModelAdmin` which shouldn't affect the cascade deletion.

Comment: I tried @dirkgroten 's suggestion. It's not ideal, since the Delete button is still there in Django Admin unnecessarily, but it works. Since my relationship is OneToOne, all I really needed in my `def delete_model(self, request, billing):` was `messages.error(request, "You cannot manually delete a billing object associated with a company")`. It prevents you from deleting a Billing object, but not from deleting a company (which indirectly deletes the Billing object). I guess I can modify the admin template to hide the button if I really want to. Thanks guys

Comment: @John Hope everything goes well! I did add another solution that will hide the button and still allow cascade deletion, but I don't recommend it, since it's comparing the request path with the expected admin change url. I'm unsure how reliable checking the url is, since I did not test bulk deletion or other means of deletion outside of a cascade delete and delete via the change page of the expected model.

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to override specifically designed for this method [get_deleted_objects](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.0/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1821) in main `Company` ModelAdmin - to allow deleting all related objects when deleting company from admin web.

```
class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_deleted_objects(self, objs, request):
        """
        Allow deleting related objects if their model is present in admin_site
        and user does not have permissions to delete them from admin web
        """
        deleted_objects, model_count, perms_needed, protected = \
            super().get_deleted_objects(objs, request)
        return deleted_objects, model_count, set(), protected
```

Here we replace `perms_needed` with empty `set()` - which is a set of permissions user failed to satisfy for deleting related objects via admin site.

---

When deleting objects via django admin it:

- checks if user has permissions to delete main object
- calculates list of other related objects that should be deleted as well
- for these related objects if their model is registered in admin_site, django performs additional permission check
- if the user has admin site permissions to delete these related objects as well
- if user does not have permissions to delete related objects - these required permissions are added to list and shown as error page

To get the list of related objects to be deleted with main one utility method is used - [get_deleted_objects](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.0/django/contrib/admin/utils.py#L103)

And since Django 2.1 there is more comfortable way to override it directly from ModelAdmin instance:
[get_deleted_objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_deleted_objects)